# Get Youtube Video Analytics of a video not owned but with public statistics

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to access the statistics for this [test video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3fEBzO1wvk) I made.
I already set in the Youtube video management the statistics to be public and I was expecting to be able to see them through the API even by using an account that is not the owner, nor the MCN of that channel.

Is this possible at all? If yes, how?

You can see already the statistics by clicking the "three dots" icon after the "share" button.

Comment: No, currently this information is not accessible via YouTube Analytics API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to view public stats of videos by using 
[videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it) from Data API.

Gave this a quick [Try-it](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it) parameters:

```
part -> statistics 
id-> {p3fEBzO1wvk} //your test video
Authorize and Execute
```

response body:

```
"statistics": {
"viewCount": "29",
"likeCount": "0",
"dislikeCount": "0",
"favoriteCount": "0",
"commentCount": "0"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Noogui, I knew about that. What I was referring to was the statistics per day provided by analytics API. The only solution I can see right now is to poll the results day by day and store it locally and with some knickknacks code mock the same results.

It's kind of nonsensical that data provided publicly for anyone to be seen in the frontend of youtube.com cannot be accessed by the APIs.